# ConEmu stopped working with Bash on Windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, conemu

I have been using ConEmu for some time to run 'bash for windows', but all of the sudden it stopped working.  When I launch a bash tab it now says:

```
ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=0.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

I think this means that it launched something, but the shell closed quickly. I haven't changed anything that I can recall with the system, it just started doing that.

Windows version: 10 (build 15063)

ConEmu version: 180626 preview

No windows updates were done recently.

If I launch 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows' from the start bar, it works fine (but I prefer using conemu as a terminal). Also, I can launch a `cmd` tab in conemu, then type `bash` and the bash shell will start. Unfortunately, launching bash in this way results in a lack of mouse support, and strange arrow key behavior.

I am at a bit of a loss.  It worked perfectly previously... then it just stopped.  Any help on how to debug or fix this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anybody finds this with a similar problem, my solution was to make a new task in ConEmu, with the command:

```
%windir%\system32\bash -l -i -cur_console:p5
```

The key is the `-cur_console:p5`, which sets the pty type as:

```
p[N] - pty modes, N - bitmask: 1 - XTermKeys, 2 - BrPaste, 4 - AppCursorKeys; default is 5 (1+4)
```

For some reason, setting `p5` is necessary for me, despite it being listed as the default. Still not sure what changed, but at least it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but (for what it's worth) found that when it happens (varying between intermittent and incessant) restarting my machine fixes the issue every time.